Class javax.ejb.Stateless is not available on the project classpath
i created on netbeans a web application project. Im just learning java ee and trying to build a simple crud application.
Im using Jakarta 10 with a glassfish 7 server with JDK 17.
I have just created a package named entities and in this package i created from netbeans "entity classes from database" so after that i just want to create a session bean for entity classes but i cant do it.
It says "Class javax.ejb.Stateless is not available on the project classpath. This might mean dependencies are missing or the target server does not support EJB Lite."
pom.xml
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jakartaee>10.0.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


javax package was renamed to jakarta package since JEE version 9 (released 2020). It looks like your Netbeans is super outdated in such way that it doesn't recognize the Jakarta transition. Either upgrade Netbeans or manually edit the package declaration in generated code or, better, simply just write code yourself. You will in long term learn, understand and remember so much more by actually typing down code with your own fingers instead of generating "unintelligible-for-you" code with mouse clicks.

Hey thanks for the answer. I am using Apache Netbeans 21 from Feb 2024.

Awkward. You might want to use another IDE instead.

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>

Add the above dependency then recreate the Session Beans for Entity.
Note: Ensure to remove the dependency when you are through and change all javax.* packaging to jakarta.

Wrong answer. There are 3 mistakes: 1) OP is using GlassFish not Tomcat or alike. 2) OP is using Jakartified version already. 3) Your dependency represents JPA not EJB.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
